# If $A\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is symmetric and satisfies [the following] then $A$ is positive definite.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

The following being:

$$A(i,i) >\sum_{j\ne i} |A(i,j)| \quad \text{for} \quad i=1,2,...,n $$

How can I prove this?

Comment: If you're trying to prove this, it is essentially a corollary of the Gerschgorin circle theorem.

Comment: Look up [diagonally dominant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix)

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be a vector with coordinates $x_{j}$.

Suppose $M =|x_{i}| = \max_{1 \leq j \leq n}|x_{j}|$.Suppose $0= \langle Ax, x \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_{i}x_{j}$.

Then $\left|-\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ii}x_{i}^{2}\right| \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j \neq i}|a_{ij}|x_{i}| |x_{j}| \implies M^{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ii} \leq M^{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\sum_{j \neq i}|a_{ij}|\right) <M^{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ii}$.

This strict inequality is a contradiction and we avoid such a contradiction only if $M =0$, but then $x =0$, which shows that $A$ is actually positive definite.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $D$ be the diagonal matrix with $D(i,i)=A(i,i)$. Then $A$ is positive definite if and only if $B=D^{-1/2}AD^{-1/2}$ is positive definite.

Consider $\|B-I\|$ under the operator norm induced by the $\infty$-norm.